# What are the "base URLs" for status, photos, etc?

Tags: facebook, api

I developed an app that looks for specific terms using the facebook api (search).

Every result comes with an ID for the item that can be of many types like "status","photos",etc.

I remember that some time ago I could surf facebook and get this URLs from the browser address bar, but now with some updates that facebook has made it seems to be all AJAX based calls and it seems like you do not have a "specific page" for each item.

I looked over the web and could not find anything regarding this.

Is there any way I can get a "photo id" from the API and open it like "http://facebook.com/photos/0293820293842"?

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture

```
https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/picture (by page id)
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/picture (by page's name)
https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture (by user id)
https://graph.facebook.com/4/zuck (by user name)
```

Comment: Hi DMCS, thanks a lot for your answer but I think I did not explained my situation in a clear way... if I use the https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/picture I get the picture without any problem... what I am looking for is a way to open the "photo album page" of that picture (the user's photo page, not the image it self)...  Thanks again... regards, Victor

Comment: The third number in the set of _ numbers is going to be the photo ID.  `http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276879_40796308305_1578420141_s.jpg` in this case 1578420141 is the photo id. The first number is the album ID, while the second # appears to be the owner id.

Comment: Thanks a lot DMCS, I will try to implement my solution using your advice... regards, Victor

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark this answer the a check :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after some time I just gave up trying to get the picture from the data provided by the `search API`.

From the api I get entries of type "`photo`" but they do not match with the API documentation found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ since I do not receive the fields `"picture"`, `"source"` or `"images"` (they just does not exist in the results from a search)

Looking to find a way to use the approach of "setting up the URL from the fields received from the API" I could not get any sucess either.

That's one case... I set up a search for "pepsi"... and within the results I got a "photo" object.

In this object I have the following fields:

```
id: 100002307882828_188072634633218  

author\id: 100002307882828

link : "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=320417371337648&set=a.133681116677942.17717.131381520241235&type=1" (this link really points to the photo's page, but is not the photo itself)

object_id: 320417371337648
```

I used the URL you provided as a "base" and tried to setup some combination that returns me a photo but I always get "Content not found" as result.

The only way I could find the final photo URL is to make another call to the API using the Photo Id as parameter (but I would need to do a lot of calls to the API and this just do not fit my scenario)

If I call `https://graph.facebook.com/320417371337648` I get everything I need from the photo, but this is the "another call" I would need to perform for each result I get.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Regards,
Victor Reboucas